# ASP.NET MVC 4 - RouteConfig.cs - updated locally, works - doesn't update on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an asp.net MVC 4 app.

This is the RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Home", "home", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        routes.MapRoute("Pricing", "pricing", new { controller = "Home", action = "Pricing" });
        routes.MapRoute("AboutUs", "aboutus", new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs" });


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I deployed this fresh to a Windows 2012 server. Worked fine. The routes remove /home/ from some URLs - eg:

```
mydomain.com/home/pricing
```

becomes

```
mydomain.com/pricing
```

After deployment I decided to add 3 new routs - for signup flow:

```
routes.MapRoute("SignUp", "SignUp", new { controller = "Myuser", action = "SignUp" });
routes.MapRoute("SignUp2", "SignUp2", new { controller = "Myuser", action = "SignUp2" });
routes.MapRoute("SignUpEnd", "SignUpEnd", new { controller = "Myuser", action = "SignUpEnd" });
```

Just above the Default route. They are there to change:

```
mydomain.com/myuser/signup
```

to

```
mydomain.com/signup
```

They worked fine locally. However when I deployed the new RouteConfig.cs to the server - none of the new routes are recognized (and the old ones still are).

I tried restarting the website in IIS, and different browsers even different computers - no effect.

I can find nothing on Google.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious - how can I get the updated routes to be recognized on the server?

Comment: You wouldn't deploy `RouteConfig.cs` to the server. You would compile it into an assembly and deploy the *assembly* to the server. The most practical way to deploy is to use the publish feature of Visual Studio.

Comment: why would you do it this way? Any links etc?

Comment: [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying to Test](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

Comment: Is it - put very simply, in essence - not just a case of "uploading the bin folder"?

Comment: I have used web deploy in the past - its was OK - although does bring new challenges with it. There's a lot to be said for the simplicity of SFTP. There are 2 considerations here - what to upload, and how to upload it. What to upload is "the bin folder" - how to upload it is another question. I agree web deploy is one option - although it doesn't directly address the question?! (either way I do appreciate you input).

Comment: Visual Studio Publish is the tool you can use to decide "what to upload". You can set it up to deploy to a local folder, and then use SFTP on the contents of the folder. You could further automate the process from the command line if you so choose and use a CI server like TeamCity or Jenkins to automate the build and versioning and use Web Deploy to push to the server (which is far better than FTP because it automatically determines if a file needs to be updated and deploys only when necessary). But, regardless of how you deploy, `.cs` files need to be compiled into assemblies prior.

Comment: Yep all good options - CI is defo on my todo list. My FTP client does look at files to see if they have been changed - although uploading more files than required isn't a huge deal in my scenarios.

Aren't .cs files always compiled into assemblies into the bin folder when you build/run locally in any case? thx.

Comment: Yes they are, but the local project has all of the source files that are unnecessary to put on the target server. Publishing does both the compile and removes the files from the deployment package that you don't need to deploy (and in some cases, might be a security risk to deploy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy MVC apps (as opposed to Web Forms 'websites') - only using the dlls in the Bin directory.

Deploy the bin directory only - the site does not compile dynamically on the web server.

Once I uploaded the Bin directory - it updated.